# Json形式のAPIによる複数レコード作成

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

rails+AngularJSでAPIを利用して投稿に複数のタグを同時につけることやろうとしていますが、
うまくいきません。アドバイスいただけないでしょうか。

<やりたいこと>
ポストに対して1回のAPIで複数のタグレコードを検索、作成する。

＜POSTするJsonイメージ＞

```
[{name: 'tag1'},{name: 'tag2'}]
```

＜APIの処理＞

```
#ポストに紐づくタグの更新
resource "posts/:id/tag" do
  desc "投稿に紐づくタグ作成"
  params do
    requires :id, type: Integer, desc: "Post id."
  end
  post do
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    params[:name].each do |name|
      @post.tags.find_or_create_by({name: name)
    end
  end
end
```

上記の処理で下記のようなNoMethodErrorのエラーがでてしまいます。
そちら酒精したのですが、治らず。。。
下記のようなエラーが出ています。

````
NoMethodError at /api/v1/posts/1/tag
==================================== > undefined method `each' for "tag1":String app/api/aplication/api.rb, line 103
-------------------------------
``` ruby 
   98 params do 
   99   requires :id, type: Integer, desc: "Post id." 
  100 end 
  101 post do 
  102   @post = Post.find(params[:id])
> 103   params[:name].each do |name| 
  104     @post.tags.find_or_create_by({ 
  105       name: name 
  106     }) 
  107   end 
  108 end
``` App backtrace -------------

app/api/cospic/api.rb:103:in `block (2 levels) in ' Full backtrace --------------
app/api/cospic/api.rb:103:in `block (2 levels) in '
grape (0.10.1) lib/grape/endpoint.rb:47:in `block in generate_api_method'
grape (0.10.1) lib/grape/endpoint.rb:247:in `run'
grape (0.10.1) lib/grape/endpoint.rb:195:in `block in call!'
grape (0.10.1) lib/grape/middleware/base.rb:24:in `call!'
grape (0.10.1) lib/grape/middleware/base.rb:18:in `call'
grape (0.10.1) lib/grape/middleware/base.rb:24:in `call!'
grape (0.10.1) lib/grape/middleware/base.rb:18:in `call'
grape (0.10.1) lib/grape/middleware/error.rb:27:in `block in call!'
grape (0.10.1) lib/grape/middleware/error.rb:26:in `call!'
grape (0.10.1) lib/grape/middleware/base.rb:18:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/builder.rb:138:in `call'
grape (0.10.1) lib/grape/endpoint.rb:196:in `call!'
grape (0.10.1) lib/grape/endpoint.rb:184:in `call'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:152:in `block in call'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:96:in `block in recognize'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:68:in `optimized_each'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:95:in `recognize'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:141:in `call'
grape (0.10.1) lib/grape/api.rb:102:in `call'
grape (0.10.1) lib/grape/api.rb:33:in `call!'
grape (0.10.1) lib/grape/api.rb:29:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:73:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:678:in `call'
omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/builder.rb:59:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/config.rb:17:in `call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/migration.rb:380:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:57:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.1.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.1.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.1.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
railties (4.1.6) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
railties (4.1.6) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
/Users/masah/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/Users/masah/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/Users/masah/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'a
````

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON側とRuby側でKeyが異なる（`tag_name`と`name`になっている）点と、Ruby側で`params_tags`をハッシュのように扱っている点が怪しい気がします。

Keyを一致させて、かつ渡されたパラメータをeachで回す部分を修正するとこんな感じになると思います。

```
params[:tag_name].each do |name|
  # ブロック引数のnameはStringであるはず
  @post.tags.find_or_create_by(name: name)
end
```

それでも直らない場合はlog/development.logを開き、リクエスト発生（`Started POST`以降）からエラーで出力されるスタックトレースの最後までを追記してください。

#### 追記

ログを見たところ、パラメータの送信もしくはRuby側のパラメータの扱いが意図した通りに行われていないようです。（`params[:name]`の中身が配列ではなくただの文字列になっている）

ログの中の`Started POST ...`から`Parameters: ...`の部分を確認すると、渡されたパラメータの中身を確認できます。

ログの出力例

```
Started POST "/news_releases" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-15 09:59:09 +0900
Processing by NewsReleasesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "news_release"=>{"title"=>"BigCo switches to Rails", "released_on"=>"2013-07-29", "body"=>"BigCo has released a new website built with open source."}, "commit"=>"Create News release"}
```

ログを見ても問題が解決しない場合は、その部分を追記してください。
（解決した場合もその旨追記してくださいね）

Comment: ご指摘頂いた点を修正したのですが、治らず。
エラーを追記いたしました。

Comment: ありがとうございます！
渡されたパラメータを確認し、解決しました！